# Android handwriting recognition library

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, handwriting-recognition

I am currently using tess-two library for OCR in Android, which gives us a result based on input image and training data. What I wish to do is build my own training data based on previous handwriting data. I looked through how to train data on a Linux system using tesseract:
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Does tesseract have support for doing something like this on android?
Any other library which provides such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

`tesseract` is primarily coded in C++. If you make use of the Native Development Kit (NDK) Google provides for Android, you can use all its classes.
Alternatively, you can try to code a similar learning system based on tesseract's in Java.